# Float Value being Truncated in RoR 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When saving my longtitude and latitude in my Rails 3.2 app, the value's getting truncated on save.

I've tried in the console and it's saving the full value:

```
 item.update_attributes(:latitude => '51.07763839854951')

 item.latitude:

 => 51.07763839854951
```

Saving the same value in the browser gives me an output of:

```
 51.0865174
```

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Instead of doing `item.latitude` in the console do `item.reload.latitude`; does that give you a different result?

Comment: Changed to a decimal as suggested below - might have a play with this later. It still seems a bit weird.

Comment: After you changed the DB field to a decimal field, does it still truncate the value? Please post the results you get now.

Comment: Just been investigating and the field is still truncated!! 51.1210398 is the output despite having precision 30 and scale 20 set. Must be a rails thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is probably being truncated when it is stored in the DB. Regardless of the exact cause, if this value is precise and needs to be stored and retrieved losslessly, a floating-point number is probably the wrong data type to use. Floating point numbers can lose precision when you perform certain arithmetic operations on them, so they are not appropriate for values which must be exact.

When you are defining your DB schema using Rails migrations, you can use the `:decimal` type for decimal values which must be stored precisely. (When ActiveRecord pulls these values out of the DB, they will become `BigDecimal` objects rather than `Float`s You can do arithmetic on `BigDecimal`s without losing precision.)